# Is the complement of this decision problem in $P$?

Tags: algorithms, primes

*Are there any two primes that are **NOT** a factor of $M$ that multiply up to $M$?*

**Fact:** Any two primes that multiply up to $M$. Must be factors of $M$!

Thus because of the fact above an $O(1)$ algorithm exists. It always outputs $NO$

### Complement

*Are there any two primes that are a factor of $M$ that multiply up to $M$?*

**Fact:** A complement of a decision problem does not always require to always return $YES$ or $NO$. It can be either one!

(eg. $M$ = 6 and two primes that multiply up to $M$ are $3$,$2$.)

Well, this I find interesting this is deciding $Semi-Primes$.

### Question

Shouldn't $Semi-Primes$ be in $P$, because what was shown above?

Comment: Well, it can't be a prime for the original decision problem because primes only have $1$, $prime$ and $1$ is not $prime$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3728251/14578

Answer (score 1):

Careful how you come up with a complement. The original problem asks to satisfy the following, given M:
$$\exists p,q: ((p\text{ and } q \text{ are prime})\land \neg(p\mid M)\land \neg(q\mid M) \land (pq=M))$$
As you say, the answer is always NO.

The complement of the problem should by definition have the opposite answer (YES) for ever $M$. To see why that's the case, negate the original problem (carefully):
$$\neg\exists p,q: ((p\text{ and } q \text{ are prime})\land \neg(p\mid M)\land \neg(q\mid M) \land (pq=M))$$
Distributing through the $\exists$ gives:
$$\forall p,q: \neg((p\text{ and } q \text{ are prime})\land \neg(p\mid M)\land \neg(q\mid M) \land (pq=M))$$
And distributing again makes this pretty trivial:
$$\forall p,q: ((p\text{ or } q \text{ is not prime})\lor (p\mid M)\lor (q\mid M) \lor (pq\ne M))$$
So the complement is really asking: *Given $M$, is it true that every pair of numbers $p$ and $q$ either has a non-prime or a divisor of $M$ or they don't multiply to $M$?* It's a bit strange to claim this, but it's always true.

Comment: Consider this, if the Goldbach Conjecture is false. Given even $N$ > 2, is there NOT two primes that sum up to $N$? If the conjecture is false the output could be yes or no.